# In Business Rules Engines, is there a way to address a "stale" snapshot?

Tags: drools, rule-engine

Specific environment I'm using in case it's needed: Drools, JAVA

Fairly new to BREs, but as I understand - it generates an initial snapshot of data.. then applies reasoning on the snapshot to enforce business rules. What happens if I perform data updates in between the snapshot generation and rule execution?

Is there any way to workaround this, other than limiting data updates altogether?

Answer (score 0):

Drools does not generate a "snapshot of data". The Drools engine operates on a set of objects made available to it by passing object references to the `insert` method so that the become "facts".

Any changes made to these facts result in a change of what the engine is about to do until the engine indicates that all has been done by returning from the call `fireAllRules`. The idea is to be up-to-date during rule evaluation.

If you want to analyse a static set of facts or make sure that you are looking at consistent sets of facts you'll have withhold updates or operate on cloned objects. But that is usually not what is useful and wanted.